# Android. Как программно изменить стиль View

Tags: android, style, android-button, android-themes

Есть Button и два стиля.
В зависимости от действия необходимо подменять стили программно.
Не могу найти решение, возможно ли это?

Разница в стилях минимальна:

```
    <style name="AddClientWeatherButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">

    </style>

    <style name="AddClientWeatherButtonRed" parent="AddClientWeatherButton">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_weather_toggle_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Как вариант можно программно изменить два отличающихся атрибута из стиля. С `textColor` все понятно, но как обратиться к  `colorButtonNormal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стиль `View` программно изменить нельзя.
Можно, например, заменить `View` со старым стилем на новый `View`, предварительно его сгенерировав.